# What is the name of "Software" app in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, software-center

With my install of Xubuntu, there is an application called "Software". It is the default installer for .deb packages. What is the full name of the app, and how do I launch it from the terminal?

It has such a HORRIBLY generic name, trying to google any info about it yields no useful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal name for this app is `gnome-software`. The full name is **GNOME Software**